# Kibana text field in discover but missing in lens table

Tags: kibana, kibana-7

I'm on Kibana 7.16

When I'm in discover I can see this text field:

[image]

I want the field inside of a table, but when I go to lens to try and create the table it shows up in an empty field:
[image]

In discover his is the field type:
[image]

The time and index is correct. Is it because its a mutlti line field?

Comment: Are you sure that the time range you choose is the same when you navigate to Discover or lens table? I am personally always doing the same mistake and do not choose the right time range :) If not I would check if the word is mapped as keyword.

Comment: 100% sure that im within the time range, it appears that it ignores the field if there are too many characters. But I was told that Ican use a runtime field, that didnt work either